# Ubuntu One notifies me every ten minutes that my account is full but there is nothing in it

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have checked several times and there are no files, no music, etc. in my Ubuntu One account.  Yet, every ten minutes I get a popup that tells me my account is full, and offering me the opportunity to buy more storage.

Why would I want more storage, when I don't use what I have?  How can I turn off these  reminders?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try the following:

**1.** Quit the Ubuntu One Preferences, if open

**2.** Open (Lucid): Applications->Accessories->Passwords and Encryption Keys 
(Maverick): System -> Preferences -> Password and Encryption Keys

**3.** Click on the arrow next to "Passwords"

**4.** Right-click on the Ubuntu One token and select "Delete"

**5.** Go to https://one.ubuntu.com/account/machines/

**6.** Click on the checkbox next to your computer

**7.** Click the "Remove selected computers" button

**8.** (Maverick): killall ubuntu-sso-login; u1sdtool -q; u1sdtool -c 
(Lucid): u1sdtool -q; killall ubuntuone-login; u1sdtool -c

**9.** a web page, if in Lucid, or a window, in Maverick, should open,prompting you to add your computer to your Ubuntu One account

**10.** Add your computer